# I changed my .xinitrc file and can't log into Ubuntu, how to fix it?

Tags: ubuntu, wmi

I use vim to build an empty file ~/.xinitrc as a tutorial tells me. And then I change its content to exec wmii.  wmii is the window manager I intended to use. I've already installed it on my Ubuntu.

After I reboot my computer, I can't log in with my account, flash up and back to the log in interface. But still I can log in with guest account.

Is there a way that I can fix this problem and log in with my account?

Comment: better asked at http://askubuntu.com/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you installed the packages for wmii, in the login screen you can switch your window manager/desktop environment next to the username/password, clicking in an icon.

This will be better answered in askubuntu.com

Comment: I did that, still flash out.

Comment: I found a complicate solution on askUbuntu, and finally fixed it.

Comment: @Zen by what I saw, it was quite an adventure. Happy you fixed it.